# Pop-up Appears then dissapears at MacOS Boot: Do you want the application "mediasharingd" to accept incoming network connections?

Tags: macbook-pro, catalina, permission, login, firewall

I'm running MacOS Catalina 10.15.7 (19H114) on a Macbook Pro 11,3 15" mid 2014.
Every time I log into my Mac, after about 5 seconds, I get a popup that says...

> Do you want the application "mediasharingd" to accept incoming network connections? Clicking the Deny may limit the application's behavior. This setting can be changed in the Firewall pane of Security & Privacy preferences.

After about 3/4ths of a second, the popup dissapears, and doesn't allow me to click allow or deny. This continues to happen no matter my firewall settings.

I have tried the following firewall settings:

> √ Block all incoming connections
> ☐ Automatically allow built-in software to receive incoming connections
> ☐ Automatically allow downloaded signed software to receive incoming connections
> √ Enable stealth mode

Then with:

> ☐ Block all incoming connections
>
> > mediasharingd (blocked)

> ☐ Automatically allow built-in software to receive incoming connections
> ☐ Automatically allow downloaded signed software to receive incoming connections
> ☐ Enable stealth mode

and finally with:

> ☐ Block all incoming connections
>
> > mediasharingd (blocked)

> ☐ Automatically allow built-in software to receive incoming connections
> ☐ Automatically allow downloaded signed software to receive incoming connections
> √ Enable stealth mode

Regardless of my Firewall settings, this popup continues to open, then immediately close right after login. My questions are...

1. What is mediasharingd, and how can I trace back which app is using it and where exactly it is coming from, so I can delete it?
2. Why is mediasharingd seemingly being able to request internet access before my firewall activates?
3. How do I debug this and STOP this pop-up from happening on login, and permanently block mediasharingd?

Screenshots below.

Thanks for any help!

[image: Do you want the application "mediasharingd" to accept incoming network connections? on MacOS Catalina login]

Comment: Google found this, with one answer marked Helpful. I can't test so can't add it as an answer - https://discussions.apple.com/thread/250778511 a man-page found "mediasharingd is a per-user daemon which manages the user's media library sharing.
There are no configuration options to mediasharingd. Users should not run mediasharingd manually."

Comment: @Tetsujin I will dig though this for some answers. Hopefully there is something of substance, which is relatively uncommon on the apple support forums.

Comment: Check if you have enabled [Media Sharing](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/mac-help/mchlp13371337/mac) on your macOS.

Comment: @sfxedit I do not have media sharing enabled.

Comment: I confirm identical problem that started occurring in the same timeframe & continues on Catalina 10.15.7, Macbook Pro (retina mid 2012)

Comment: A year later... after buying a new Mac Mini, and on Monterey 12.4 (presumably the latest?) and I'm now seeing this same thing. Any luck, anyone?

Comment: I cant remember how i resolved this issue. But it no longer appears. I know I did a full clean install without reimporting my backups and that probably did the trick.

Answer (score 3):

I was experiencing this myself two and a half years after this thread was written, so I thought to share what worked for me.

It makes sense to figure out if home sharing and public sharing are enabled, and if so to disable them.

First you want to open up the Terminal application on your Mac. You can find it in the "Utilities" folder within the "Applications" folder, or you can search for it using Spotlight (press Command + Space and type "Terminal").

In the Terminal, enter the followings command to check if home or public sharing are enabled:

```
defaults read com.apple.amp.mediasharingd home-sharing-enabled

defaults read com.apple.amp.mediasharingd public-sharing-enabled
```

If the commands returns anything other than 0, it means home sharing or public sharing is enabled. To disable either one, enter the following:

For home sharing:

```
defaults write com.apple.amp.mediasharingd home-sharing-enabled -bool false
```

For public sharing:

```
defaults write com.apple.amp.mediasharingd public-sharing-enabled -bool false
```

I hope this helps. Be sure to restart your system after making these changes, and please report back if it works for you!